# Offline Blog Reading (Images) capability (cache)?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am creating a UITableView where I will load and show data from my blog's feed. This data will be updated daily, on launch or dynamically.

**What I want to do is provide some offline capability to this screen, as such if user isnt connected to internet, he can still see the view and its contents (mainly post list with its images).

For such I will need some hints or solutions on how to do this, probably cache ?**

Basically if user is connected to net, the view will update the contents and fetch he blog post feeds from my API and update it with new content, but if user isnt connected to net, he should see the last fetched/updated content (with images) till he connects to net and updates the view.

For this probably I need to save/cache 3 things which I will need and use in the View, all of which are fetched and provided by my API:- The Post Title, Date and its cover image.

Would best way would be to add them to some dictionary, use NSCache (aint it temporary ?) or download images locally and then save them as UIImage along with NSString (title/date) in a dic/array ?

I would like to know as many different approaches possible.

---

After testing a bit, I found caching images can solve my offline image problem, but is cache temporary or how long can it last ? How can I store that cached image with my text data in some dictionary to load it if network isnt connected ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ready to use, opensource caching library like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It provides asynchronous image downloading as well as caching, so any image that is cached will appear in place when your app is offline.

Comment: I am actually using a similar async caching library in my other table view but what I was and am confused at is, isnt cache like temporary and deleted when system needs space or resources ? Also, the library you linked (and the one I use which is similar), we just need to add image to view via them like normal ? No need to check if network is online or not or is image is in cache or not ?

Comment: You just use the library's code to load images and it takes care for the rest.

Comment: ^^ But how about the text title and date ? Need them for offline availability aswell

Comment: Your question was about images. If you want the content offline, you have to save it in a local file or a sqlite db.

Comment: err please re-read the question, the title itself says "Blog Reading" and in description I think I mentioned 3-4 times about the post title, content, date aswell. Anyways, I was also thinking about storing the text data in a file, but should it really be independent of image cache is my doubt as stated. Btw thanks for that library, seems better one than what I am using, willwait for a few diff answers and approaches, if no better one is given, will mark yours as best one.